# How Can I find the difference between two days

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here I have two different fields the `current_day` and the `date_to_valuated_within`. In the `current_day`, I am giving my current date and converting to `day` using day function and in the `date_to_valuated_within` field I have two days Monday and Thursday. Here I have to check whether the `current_day` field lies within that `date_to_valuated_within` days.

For example,

if today() is "Monday" then it has to compare the day interval with the `date_to_valuated_within` return as TRUE

if today() is "Saturday" then it has to compare the day interval with the `date_to_valuated_within` return as FALSE

Comment: Hey Ed, If today lies within the ```date_to_valuated_within``` field then it has to return as true. Logically if today() is not weekend then it has to return as true else it should be false.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Here I leave you the solution to your issue. In the following piece of code you can find comments explaining the functioning of this function so that you can understand how and why this code is what it is.

NOTE: you will need to pass the date as '25/02/2020' for example into this function as a parameter.

```js
function checkDay(day) {
  
  // Create current date by converting the day we provide into a Date variable
  var current_day = new Date(day);
  // Convert our day into a integer (number) according to the day of the week with getDay() (for example, Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7)
  // We do this for then compare it with Monday (1) and Thursday (4) and check if it is within those values
  var current_day_number = current_day.getDay();
  
  // if the day is between monday and thursday including these days (if you don't want to include them you just need to remove the = meaning it would be either tuesday or wednesday)
  if(current_day_number>=1 && current_day_number<=4){
    return true;
  }
  // if the day is not between your desired days return false
  else{
    return false;
  }  
}

// This function is simply for testing if the one above has worked. Simply change in the run tab-> run function to test
function test(){
Logger.log(checkDay('02/23/2020'));
}
```

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isWorkDay(date) {
  const day=new Date(date).getDay();
  return (day>0 && day<6);
}
```

[Date.getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Perhaps this will help:

```
function d1isBetweend2Andd3Inclusive(d1,d2,d3) {
  const da1=new Date(d1).getDay();
  const da2=new Date(d2).getDay();
  const da3=new Date(d3).getDay();
  if(da3>da2) {
    return (da1>=da2 && da1<=da3);
  }else if(da2>da3) {
    return (da1>=da3 && da1<=da2);
  }else{
    return da1==da2;
  }
}

function d1isBetweend2Andd3NonInclusive(d1,d2,d3) {
  const da1=new Date(d1).getDay();
  const da2=new Date(d2).getDay();
  const da3=new Date(d3).getDay();
  if(da3>da2) {
    return (da1>da2 && da1<da3);
  }else if(da2>da3) {
    return (da1>da3 && da1<da2);
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cooper can you please explain me how to get this done. I am new to scripts. it would be much helpful if you share me some more info on this.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?